# How can you freely transform Objects with the Hololens?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, augmented-reality, scaling, hololens

We want to be able to freely transform objects with the HoloLens. We are currently using the BoundingBox which will scale all three axis of the objects uniform. Our goal is to stretch the object and scale every axis on their own. 
Is there an alternative to the BoundingBox or did we miss some kind of setting which allows just that?

Example video of how the solution should look like: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DJGGofLSdB8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reuse the [BoundingBox.cs](https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/mrtk_release/Assets/MixedRealityToolkit.SDK/Features/UX/Scripts/BoundingBox/BoundingBox.cs) script and modify some code to recalculate the scale value to implement free stretch.

The code from [Line 1381](https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/mrtk_release/Assets/MixedRealityToolkit.SDK/Features/UX/Scripts/BoundingBox/BoundingBox.cs#L1381) to line 1401 is scaling transform for the bounding box calculated based on the position of grab pointer. And the variable `newScala` at [line 1387](https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/mrtk_release/Assets/MixedRealityToolkit.SDK/Features/UX/Scripts/BoundingBox/BoundingBox.cs#L1387) in this script is the parameter that will be used to create the new transform with the scale of each axis. In summary, this way will reuse most of this existing code and minor changes to implement your idea.

Comment: when doing this you should create a complete copy of this script and e.g. call it `MyBoundingBox` and only make changes here. Otherwise you might get in trouble when updating the MRTK in the future

Comment: Thank you for your awnser! We kind of managed to do it but our object scales down instantly when you grab the handle. Currently we are adding (currentGrabPoint - oppositeCorner) on to initialScaleOnGrabStart.

Answer (score 0):

You can now set **Non Uniform scale** in the new **BoundsControl** script, which supersedes the old BoundingBox. This option allows you to freely transform objects on any axis.
To do this, change property "Scale Behavior" to "Non Uniform Scale", which is under  "Scale Handles Configuration" of the BoundsControl script.
https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/README_BoundsControl.html#scale-handles-configuration

Comment: You may want to be more specific. Your answer contains too few information.